# Check if the current location is within a 10-meter radius of the target coordinates?

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm trying to check if the current coordinates are within a 10-meter radius of the target coordinates. I've tried implementing a method, but I'm not sure how reliable it is. It seems to only check if the coordinates are within 1 kilometer, that's what I'm thinking, but I'm not sure if it actually creates a radius of the given number or something else entirely.

```
 punchin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                punchout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                punchin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                curLocation.setText("");
                tarLocation.setText("");
                String androidID = getIMEINumber();

                if (androidID != null) {
                    getCurrentLocation();
                    // Execute the Api's

                    double targetLatitude = 19.2185561;// Specify the latitude of the target location
                    double targetLongitude = 72.86228096;// Specify the longitude of the target location

                    float[] distanceResults = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, targetLatitude, targetLongitude, distanceResults);
                    float distanceInKm = distanceResults[0] / 1000;

                    String currentLocationStr = "Current :-" + latitude + " : " + longitude;
                    String targetLocationStr = "Target :-" + targetLatitude + " : " + targetLongitude;

                    if (distanceInKm < 1) {
                        curLocation.setText(currentLocationStr);
                        tarLocation.setText(targetLocationStr);
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "You are under office premises ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        curLocation.setText(currentLocationStr);
                        tarLocation.setText(targetLocationStr);
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "You are not under office premises ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


 private void getCurrentLocation() {
        FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext());

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Request location permissions if not already granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) requireContext(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);
        } else {
            // Permissions already granted, request current location
            fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();

                            // Use the obtained latitude and longitude values for further processing
                            // You can compare these values with your desired geolocation
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        // Handle any errors that occurred while getting the location
                    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The documentation for `Location.distanceBetween` says "[c]omputes the approximate distance in meters between two locations ...".  So, `if (distanceResults[0] < 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Documentation for [Location#distanceBetween](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D))
states the following.

> *Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations ...*

If you view the source for [Location#distanceBetween](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java#1239) you'll find it utilizes a private method called [computeDistanceAndBearing](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java#1239).

In which, the first two lines are the following developer comments.

> // Based on http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf
> // using the "Inverse Formula" (section 4)

It appears to be a complex formula; I imagine it is returning logical results.

This being said, you mentioned the following.

> ... *"It seems to only check if the coordinates are within 1 kilometer"* ...

Not according to the documentation, which states it's within meters.

Checking your `distanceResults` at index `0` should yield a number in meters.

```java
if (distanceResults[0] < 10) {
    /* within 10 meter radius */
}
```

An additional note, the Android Documentation also states the following.

> *... The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].*

You're `distanceResults` is assigned to `new float[1]`.
You should increase the size to `3`, to accommodate for these additional values.

```java
float[] distanceResults = new float[3];
```

Comment: is this correct ,

`float[] distanceResults = new float[3];
                    Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, targetLatitude, targetLongitude, distanceResults);

                    if (distanceResults[0] <= 10) {
                      
                    }`

Comment: @sagarraval, that appears correct, yes.

Comment: it is going in else condition, i have tried this too , 
`float[] distanceResults = new float[3];
                    Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, targetLatitude, targetLongitude, distanceResults);
                    float distanceInMeter = distanceResults[0] / 1000;
distanceInMeter <= 0.01`, even if im at the exact cordinates

Comment: @sagarraval, try debugging the value at index 0.  Additionally, try using [this calculator](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml) from the NWS, with your two coordinates, maybe the distance is actually greater than 10 meters.

Comment: The distance between [my latitude, my longitude] and [19.2185561, 72.86228096] is:
0.0120 km or 0.0075 mile

Comment: @sagarraval, so, 0.012 / 1000, is 12 meters.  That's why it's not matching the condition.